# GitHub branch with the same name as a tag

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github

We had a problem last week, which was that a member of our team went to our GitHub repository and searched for a tag name in the branch list in that tag/branch pulldown, and pressed return after typing in the tag name.  But it was the name of a tag, and they had the branch tab selected.  So GitHub helpfully created a branch (from master) (when the team member pressed return).  But we didn't realize that this had happened until someone tried to deploy a tag and got the branch instead.

Has anyone else had this problem?  We are trying to test deploying with tags/ instead, but we have 2 deployment environments, one on AWS and the other based on capistrano.  Our version capistrano apparently doesn't like that syntax, and if you use refs/tags/ it will strip the "refs/tags/" part and use just the .  So that got me worried about what AWS is doing.  I am now trying to investigate that, but I'm not very great at Chef, so I thought I would ask here.

Is there a way to prevent creating branches with the same name as a tag in GitHub?  Does AWS use the `tags/` part or strip that out?

Answer (score 1):

An avenue you may want to explore is to write a client-side [pre-push hook](http://blog.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2013/09/03/git-pre-push/).

If the pre-push hook exits `0`, it will prevent push. If it exits `1`, it allows the push to proceed.

According to the documentation:

> This hook is called by git push and can be used to prevent a push from
>   taking place. The hook is called with two parameters which provide the
>   name and location of the destination remote, if a named remote is not
>   being used both values will be the same.
>
> Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook’s
>   standard input with lines of the form:
>
> `<local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF` For
>   instance, if the command git push origin master:foreign were run the
>   hook would receive a line like the following:
>
> `refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345`

I could imagine a simple script that checks for the existence of "branch" in the `<local ref>` and exits with the message `"use tags, not branches"` or something.

In order to propagate hooks to your repository, you will need to [set a hookPath using git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_description).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you rename the branch?

```
git branch -m new_name old_name
```

Even the reflog will be preserved.

Comment: We don't need the new branch.  We didn't know it got created.  The team member was just searching for a tag, and pressed return after typing in the tag name, and didn't even know they had created a branch.